# How to disable a particular mock for a particular test case?

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-juno, jmockit

Actually i have written 5 test cases for a particular method in a class. There is a statement in that method which calls a method from another class and i don't want to test that class so I have used a mock for that class. Now i want that while running the 5th test case it shouldn't visit that mocked class instead it should visit the original class. How to do it?

thanks in advance...

Comment: what mocking library do you use? could you paste some of your code that you have problem with? I assume you could easily achieve this via setting up your mock data in your test cases.

Comment: i am using jmockit library for mocking.

Answer (score 0):

In the setup of that particular test either call the appropriate constructor of the object under test or construct a new object under test with the non-mocked instance. Another option would be to use Mockito. In Mockito you can `spy` an object. This would allow you to stub out the method (mock it) by default but in the one test have the spy forward to the actual instance.

[Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html)

[Spy Annotation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html)